# Mandatory to add spring-boot-starter-* dependencies in child module only?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-starter

I have one parent module (A) which is already included / imported into the child module (B) as dependency.

***Module A***.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>*some-version*<version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

***Module B***

```
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
                <version>*module-A-version*<version>
            </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Question : There is no error in compilation and a war artifact for module B (B.war) is created successfully. But when I deploy module B (i.e. B.war) it fails on following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/YamlProcessor
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:57)
> at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:127)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:462)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:449)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:374)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:210)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:179)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:152)
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
> at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
> at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:325)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
> at com.propspace.intl.gateway.GatewayInternational.main(GatewayInternational.java:32)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
> ... 32 more

Is it like we always have to include *spring-boot-starter-** in the leaf module and it can not be defined in one common parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing couple of PoC about pom-starters it is confirmed that only `deployable` service should have respective pom-starters defined in its `pom.xml`.

Hence w.r.t above hierarchy child **`B`** must have definition as follows,

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>*some-version*<version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Parent **`A`** can contain any other common dependencies which are not pom-starters.